# Need help to understand how sceneRect in Qt works

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in Qt. I read tutorials but I still don't understand how sceneRect works.

When I run this code the image (green) is shown in the middle (probably default position, right?)

**MyApplication.cpp**

```
ui.setupUi(this);    

ui.graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);
_graphicsScene = make_unique<QGraphicsScene>(this);
ui.graphicsView->setScene(_graphicsScene.get());

_graphicsScene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::blue);

QImage img("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\img.png");
auto pixImg = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
pixImg = pixImg.scaled(QSize(50, 50), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixImg);
_graphicsScene->addPixmap(pixImg);
```

[image]

**ui_MyApplication.h**

```
void setupUi(QMainWindow *MyApplicationToolClass)
{
    if (MyApplicationToolClass->objectName().isEmpty())
        MyApplicationToolClass->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MyApplicationToolClass"));
    MyApplicationToolClass->resize(465, 372);
    centralWidget = new QWidget(MyApplicationToolClass);
    centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
    entitiesView = new QGraphicsView(centralWidget);
    entitiesView->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("entitiesView"));
    entitiesView->setGeometry(QRect(30, 20, 401, 281));
    MyApplicationToolClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    menuBar = new QMenuBar(MyApplicationToolClass);
    menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
    menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 465, 21));
    MyApplicationToolClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
    mainToolBar = new QToolBar(MyApplicationToolClass);
    mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
    MyApplicationToolClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
    statusBar = new QStatusBar(MyApplicationToolClass);
    statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
    MyApplicationToolClass->setStatusBar(statusBar);

    retranslateUi(MyApplicationToolClass);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MyApplicationToolClass);
} // setupUi
```

I thought if I set the `sceneRect` to `(0,0,100,100)` by `_entitiesScene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 100);` the image will be shown in the top-left corner but it just shifts a little bit up.

[image]

I set the `sceneRect` to `(50,50,100,100)` it justs shifts up and left

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the "enlarged the bounding rectangle". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please, forget everything I told you yesterday in comments - most was non-sense. (It was late on my side -> would've been better to keep quiet.) I fiddled this out and wrote a respective answer which (hopefully) will clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

Short review of sceneRect of scene, boundingRect of items:

[**`QGraphicsItem::boundingRect`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect):

> This pure virtual function defines the outer bounds of the item as a rectangle; all painting must be restricted to inside an item's bounding rect. QGraphicsView uses this to determine whether the item requires redrawing.
>
> Although the item's shape can be arbitrary, the bounding rect is always rectangular, and it is unaffected by the items' transformation.

[**`QGraphicsScene::sceneRect`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)

> This property holds the scene rectangle; the bounding rectangle of the scene
>
> The scene rectangle defines the extent of the scene. It is primarily used by QGraphicsView to determine the view's default scrollable area, and by QGraphicsScene to manage item indexing.
>
> If unset, or if set to a null QRectF, sceneRect() will return the largest bounding rect of all items on the scene since the scene was created (i.e., a rectangle that grows when items are added to or moved in the scene, but never shrinks).

The scene rect might be set explicitly. This will influence the rendering in view. If the scene is claimed to be different from the bounding rect of all items, the view will consider this respectively.

The missing piece of OP is IMHO that there is something else which is considered in rendering:

[**`QGraphicsView::alignment`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop)

> This property holds the alignment of the scene in the view when the whole scene is visible.
>
> If the whole scene is visible in the view, (i.e., there are no visible scroll bars,) the view's alignment will decide where the scene will be rendered in the view. For example, if the alignment is Qt::AlignCenter, which is default, the scene will be centered in the view, and if the alignment is (Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop), the scene will be rendered in the top-left corner of the view.)

To do this, the `QGraphicsView` considers its own view size and the scene rect and computes the respective translation to achieve the required alignment. The translation is used to update the [`QGraphicsView::transform`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#setTransform) which maps scene coordinates to viewport coordinates.

A small sample to illustrate this (`testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.cc`):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

// returns a random floating point number in [min, max).
qreal randF(qreal min, qreal max)
{
  return qrand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (max - min) + min;
}

// returns a random color.
QColor randColor()
{
  return QColor(
    (int)256 * randF(0.0, 1.0),
    (int)256 * randF(0.0, 1.0),
    (int)256 * randF(0.0, 1.0));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  qWin.setWindowTitle("QSceneGraph::sceneRect Demo");
  QToolBar qToolbar;
  QAction qCmdAdd("Add Rect");
  qToolbar.addAction(&qCmdAdd);
  QAction qCmdClear("Clear Scene");
  qToolbar.addAction(&qCmdClear);
  qToolbar.addSeparator();
  QWidget qEditAlign;
  QGridLayout qGridAlign; QButtonGroup qBtnGrp;
  QRadioButton qBtnTL, qBtnTC, qBtnTR;
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnTL, 0, 0);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnTL, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnTC, 0, 1);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnTC, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnTR, 0, 2);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnTR, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);
  QRadioButton qBtnCL, qBtnCC, qBtnCR;
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnCL, 1, 0);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnCL, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnCC, 1, 1);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnCC, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnCR, 1, 2);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnCR, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
  QRadioButton qBtnBL, qBtnBC, qBtnBR;
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnBL, 2, 0);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnBL, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnBC, 2, 1);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnBC, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignBottom);
  qGridAlign.addWidget(&qBtnBR, 2, 2);
  qBtnGrp.addButton(&qBtnBR, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);
  qEditAlign.setLayout(&qGridAlign);
  qToolbar.addWidget(&qEditAlign);
  qWin.addToolBar(&qToolbar);
  QGraphicsView qGView;
  QGraphicsScene qGScene;
  qGView.setScene(&qGScene);
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qGView);
  qWin.show();
  // activate button for default align of qGView
  qBtnGrp.button(qGView.alignment())->setChecked(true);
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qCmdAdd, &QAction::triggered,
    [&]() {
      // add rect
      QRectF qRect(
        randF(-50.0, 50.0), randF(-50.0, 50.0),
        randF(10.0, 100.0), randF(10.0, 100.0));
      qGScene.addRect(qRect, QPen(randColor(), 2), randColor());
      // report
      qDebug() << "new rect:" << qRect;
      qDebug() << "scene rect:" << qGScene.sceneRect();
      qDebug() << "scene (0, 0) in view at:"
        << qGView.mapFromScene(QPointF(0.0, 0.0));
      qDebug() << "top left view corner in scene at:"
        << qGView.mapToScene(QPoint(0, 0));
    });
  QObject::connect(&qCmdClear, &QAction::triggered,
    [&]() {
      // clear scene
      qGScene.clear();
      // reset sceneRect
      qGScene.setSceneRect(QRect());
    });
  QObject::connect(&qBtnGrp,
    (void(QButtonGroup::*)(int, bool))&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled,
    [&](int id, bool checked) {
      if (checked) qGView.setAlignment((Qt::Alignment)id);
    });
  // run time loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The corresponding Qt project (`testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.pro`):

```
SOURCES = testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.pro

$ make && ./testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.o testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.cc
g++  -o testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.exe testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
new rect: QRectF(-4.13499,25.5605 21.8384x10.0007)
scene rect: QRectF(-5.13499,24.5605 23.8384x12.0007)
scene (0, 0) in view at: QPoint(120,3)
top left view corner in scene at: QPointF(-120,-3)
new rect: QRectF(-46.5428,33.0965 56.7475x44.5152)
scene rect: QRectF(-47.5428,24.5605 66.2462x54.0512)
scene (0, 0) in view at: QPoint(141,-17)
top left view corner in scene at: QPointF(-141,17)
```

[image: Snapshot of testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect (two rects added)]

Afterwards, I changed the alignment by mouse click:

```
scene (0, 0) in view at: QPoint(47,-24)
top left view corner in scene at: QPointF(-47,24)
```

[image: Snapshot of testQGraphicsSceneSceneRect (alignment changed to top left)]