# QGraphicsView clips an image when resizing larger that the starting width

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am adding a compass to the top right corner of a QGraphicsView like so:

```
ui.compass = new QLabel(viewport());
ui.compass->setPixmap(pm);
ui.compass->setContentsMargins(viewport()->width() - pm.width() - 2, 2, 0, 0);
```

When the QGraphicsView is resized, I simply reset the left margin (the same code as the last line above) to keep it on the right.

The problem happens when I resize the QGraphicsView to any width wider than when the application started, in which case, the compass is clipped (as seen in the screenshot below) and eventually disappears completely, as if there is an invisible curtain is slides behind. When resizing smaller than the initial size, all works as expected. After resizing smaller, it can be resized larger also without issue until reaching that initial width again.

**Edit**: the application saves the geometry on close and restores next start up. If I resize the window to be larger, such that compass is not visible, close the application and start it again, the graphics view starts as the larger size and the compass is visible, until I try to resize wider again.

**Edit 2**: added minimum working example. Just resize the application wider than start up and watch the compass image disappear.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    MyGraphicsView()
        : pm(":/images/Compass.svg")
        , compass(new QLabel(viewport()))
    {
        compass->setPixmap(pm);
    }
private:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override
    {
        QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);

        QMargins margins = compass->contentsMargins();
        margins.setLeft(viewport()->width() - pm.width() - 2);
        compass->setContentsMargins(margins);
    }

    QLabel* compass;
    QPixmap pm;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow win;
    win.setCentralWidget(new MyGraphicsView());
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Did you try to update the [sceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) after resize? (FYI: [SO: Need help to understand how sceneRect in Qt works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55771786/7478597))

Comment: Yes, updating the scene rectangle did nothing. Add `setSceneRect(0.0f, 0.0f, event->size().width(), event->size().height());` to resizeEvent() in the example code